# Cannot get ng-click working for either div or span

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-click` for both a `div` and a `span` and can't get it working for either.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-click="infoClicked('work_please')">
       tony magoo  
    </div>
    <div>
       For general inquiries, please see our <span class = "highlight" ng-click = "infoClicked('work_span_please')">Frequently Asked Questions</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

and...

```
var app = angular.module( 'plunker', [] );
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.infoClicked = function( message ) {
        alert( message );
    }
});
```

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SuZDOjJxfFIxgYff6HMz?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the **ng-app** tag.

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Comment: ah so the ng-app fixes it.  Yeah?

Comment: @BreakoBreako Yes. ng-app tells angular to be active in which portion of the page.

Comment: what if you'r working with no ng-app ? somthing like  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap or https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data